# How to fix `plex-otf.sty` not found

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave, xelatex

I am trying to compile an Rsweave document. I recently migrated from a Macbook to a Thinkpad running rhel.

Previously on my macbook after simply downloading and in stalling the fonts, a document wih the following header would compile.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usefilenames,DefaultFeatures={Ligatures=Common}]{plex-otf} %
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
```

However now it returns the error `plex-otf.sty` not found.

I tried copying the plex-otf.sty file from the latex package into the directory with no luck.

heres the log from xelatex

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=xelatex 2023.2.3)  3 FEB 2023 17:21
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Onboarding.tex
(./Onboarding.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.17> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 105.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count87
\Gm@cntv=\count88
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
)

! LaTeX Error: File `plex-otf.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.5 \renewcommand
                 *\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the...
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 958 strings out of 494986
 12180 string characters out of 6178606
 68285 words of memory out of 5000000
 4860 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6638 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,0n,19p,246b,74s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

How do I make latex see this package?

Comment: Texlive2018 sounds awfully old.

Comment: I'm not certain it will work with your old (probably unsupported) version of TeXlive, but in current TeXlive you could install the package with this command:  `tlmgr install plex-otf`.